how to convert htlm language to app languge
How to convert HTML language to APP language
I tried to convert IN VS Code. It did not work. VS code is text editor and VS Code doesnot support app language. Donot tried in other text editor. This didnot answwr any of the question.

You should explain more about what you are trying to do. Also what do you mean by converting HTML Language to App Language?

You cannot convert from HTML language to "app language". Programming languages are not like speaking languages, and cannot simply be translated. HTML is a completely different type of language than languages that would be used to develop apps. I would suggest using an editor such as NetBeans if you wanted to make an app from scratch, using your current HTML project as a base.
